# Google Street View Image Direction

Tags: google-street-view

I'm trying to get an image of a certain latlng heading towards the direction of the google car.

Here is the [link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988&heading=degrees&pitch=0&sensor=false) I use to get the image.

By using no "**degrees**" shows sometimes the image heading towards the latlng and sometimes backwards that point. This seems to be completely weird for me.

So I decided to get my own algorithm by getting the next leg of the route and by getting the slope of those 2 points and the arctan I get the angle and some more math ecuations but it is never acurate, why is this?

Is it possible to get the image heading towards the direction of the vehicle?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. To clarify: you want to get a series of images along the track, like they would look if you were sitting in the vehicle and looking to the front?

Comment: I'll put it clearer. I'm creating routes and I want to get the image of the start latlng heading towards the path that gets me to the end latlng, not heading the end latlng, but the path that gets you there. So imagine you are in your car, you start driving from the start point of the route heading the road that gets you to the end point. I want that first image of the road.